# Routing is not working and page display blank?

Tags: angularjs

This below code, I am trying to use routing. Though the URL changes, the page remains blank. The console doesn't throw any error either.

#### html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#!/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/about">AboutUs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/whatwedo">WhatWeDo</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

```
var app =  angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('#!/',{
        templateUrl : 'main.htm'
    })

    .when('#!/about',{
        templateUrl : 'about.htm'
    })

    .when('#!/contact',{
        templateUrl : 'contact.htm'
    })

    .when('#!/whatwedo',{
        templateUrl : 'whatwedo.htm'
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hash-bangs from the routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'main.htm'
    })

    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl : 'about.htm'
    })

    .when('/contact',{
        templateUrl : 'contact.htm'
    })

    .when('/whatwedo',{
        templateUrl : 'whatwedo.htm'
    })

});
```